# Get referrer details after installing app from Play store

Tags: android, google-analytics, deep-linking, branch.io, referrals

I am using Branch for deferred deep linking and I am trying to find all referral data after installing app from play store. I have added Google Analytics Campaign Parameters to Google Play URL as recommended. like.

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_term%3D3208%26utm_content%3D47321%26utm_campaign%3D64856](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%3Cpackage%20name%3E&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_term%3D3208%26utm_content%3D47321%26utm_campaign%3D64856)

but I am getting referral details for "utm_source : google-play" and for "utm_medium : organic" which is not correct.

I have also try to get referral data by broadcasting referral details from android studio's terminal like.

> adb shell
>   am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n / --es "referrer" "utm_source=google&utm_medium=linkedin&utm_term=3208&utm_content=37413&utm_campaign=invite"

and it works well.

So plz help me out.

Comment: Could you share the Branch Link you click before being redirected to the Play Store?

Comment: Branch Link: https://r87m.test-app.link/B0JwhDeTyD and https://r87m.test-app.link/p19SsjDSyD

Comment: Where are you retrieving these referral details? Inside the app, or through Google Analytics?

Comment: I am retrieving these referral details in Broadcastreceiver    
 <receiver android:name=".Track.TrackingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Answer (score 3):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Branch doesn't overwrite the INSTALL_REFERRER, so these incorrect `utm_source` and `utm_medium` values are not coming from our system. Sometimes the INSTALL_REFERRER is delayed — is it possible you might have been testing multiple links with different values set in rapid succession?

*Side note: Branch does also use the INSTALL_REFERRER for other purposes, so you may want to review [our docs on how to use it for both Branch and your own needs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/advanced/android/#custom-install-referrer-class).*

**More generally though**, Branch makes the INSTALL_REFERRER obsolete. The point of the INSTALL_REFERRER was to allow you to pass values through the install process, and storing UTM parameters there is a hack to give you some basic visibility into your acquisition channels. Branch allows you to do both of these things with far more power and precision, so you really shouldn't need to be using the INSTALL_REFERRER for this at all. Check out the Branch docs pages for [storing link data](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/) and [setting up the Google Analytics integration](https://dev.branch.io/data-exchange/google-analytics/) for more details.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the response.We enabled the google analytics integration. How do we see the data analytics in the google analytics console?

Comment: No problem! You should be able to see it in Acquisition > Sources > All